# How do I change the index page in a CodeIgniter anchor?

Tags: codeigniter, indexing, anchor

So, I have two different applications in my CodeIgniter installation.  One is admin, the other is frontend.  I basically just copied the index file, renamed it "admin.php", and changed the application directory to "application/admin".  I then changed the application directory in index.php to "application/frontend".

What I would like to do is create a link on the frontend application that takes you to the admin application.  The variable config['index_page'] in the frontend application is set to "index.php" and in the admin application it's set to "admin.php".

Is there a way to set the url helper to use "admin.php" instead of "index.php"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that way.
you should make or use an authentication library and you set different roles for different
users.
you just after login can put the redirection to your admin controller.
and for other users and viewers you can redirect them to any other controllers.
for viewers you can just use something like this:
    Code:
       if(!$this->m_auth->is_logged_in())
    {
         $this->viewers();
    }
    else
    {
         $this->users();
    }

In your users function you just check different roles and redirect according.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some codeigniter concept, and you are trying to do it the normal way, i suggest you to read this [article](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth) , you will how you can use `MY_Controller` as same concept of front controller and how you will be able to give every use specific roles

another way is to use a ready made authentication library as @medhi said
I would recommend [Tank Authentication](https://github.com/TankAuth/Tank-Auth)   or [Ion Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)

I